# Data structure to check for pairs?

Tags: java, data-structures

Say I have objects A,B,C,D. They can contain references to one another, for example, A might reference  B and C, and C might reference A. I want to create segments but dont want to create them twice, so I don't want segment A C and segment C A, just 1 of them. So I want to keep a list of created segments, ex: A C, and check if I already have an A C or C A and skip it if so.

Is there a data structure that can do this?

Thanks

```
if(list.contains(a,b)
{
   //dont add
}
```

Comment: what about the following segment:  `A B C` would that also remove all 3 character permutations of it as well?  Or just the segment in reverse?

Comment: @Woot4Moo Segments only have 2 nodes in this case, segment A B C is not possible, it would be Segment A B, and segment B C.

Comment: Ok I have something that could work posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may introduce something like

```
class PairKey<T extends Comparable<T>> { 
  final T fst, snd;
  public PairKey(T a, T b) {
    if (a.compareTo(b) <=0 ) {
      fst = a;
      snd = b;
    } else {
      fst = b;
      snd = a;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return a.hashCode() & 37 & b.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == this) return true;
    if (!(other instanceOf PairKey)) return false;
    PairKey<T> obj = (PairKey<T>) other;
    return (obj.fst.equals(fst) && obj.snd.equals(snd));
  }
}
```

then you may put edges into HashSet < PairKey < ? extends Comparable> > and then check if the given pair is already there.

You will need to make your vertexes comparable, so it will be possible to treat PairKey(A,B) equal to PairKey(B,A)

And then HashSet will do the rest for you, e.g you will be able to query

```
pairs.contains(new PairKey(A,B));
```

and if pairs contain either PairKey(A,B) or PairKey(B,A) - it will return true.

hashCode implementation might be slightly different, may be IDE will generate something more sophisticated.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an object called `Pair` that would look something like this:

```
class Pair  
{  
    Node start;  
    Node end;  

    public Pair(Node start, Node end)  
    { 
      this.start=start;
      this.end=end;  
    }  

   public Pair reverse()  
   {  
       return new Pair(end,start);  
   }  
}
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
if(pairs.contains(currentPair) || pairs.contains(currentPair.reverse())  
{  
    continue;
}  else{  
     pairs.add(currentPair);  
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, you will need to implement equals and hashcode.  However, doing the check in equals to make it match the reversal of the segment is a bad practice in a pure OO since.  By implementing equals in the fashion, described within the comments, would bind Pair to your application only and remove the portability of it.

Comment: Without implementing equals and hashCode, it wouldn't work. And why use a reverse method rather than implementing equals so that two pairs are equal if they contain the same nodes, whatever the order is?

Comment: @JBNizet primarily because I am writing this from a mobile phone and it was something quick and dirty.

Comment: @JBNizet updated my response to include that,so other people don't miss it.

Comment: Your response was indeed dirty, hence the downvote. And OOP is all about encapsulating the appropriate behevior. It's not about making all the classes potentially reusable by not implementing the appropriate requirements.

Comment: You have to be careful to implement a correct `hashCode`. Assuming that `equals` returns `true` when two instances of `Pair` differ only in the order of `start` and `end`, then `hashCode` needs to compute the same hash code regardless of the order of `start` and `end`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set of sets of objects.

```
Set<Set<MyObjectType>> segments = new HashSet<Set<MyObjectType>>();
```

Then you can add two-element sets representing pairs of `MyObject`. Since sets are unordered, if `segments` contains a set with A and B, attempting to add a set containing B and A will treat it as already present in `segments`.

```
Set<MyObjectType> segment = new HashSet<MyObjectType>();
segment.add(A); // A and B are instances of MyObjectType
segment.add(B);
segments.add(segment);
segment = new HashSet<MyObjectType>();
segment.add(B);
segment.add(A);
segments.add(segment);
System.out.println("Number of segments: " + segments.size()); // prints 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.Set`/ `java.util.HashSet` and keep adding the references you find e.g.

```
   Set set1 = new HashSet();
   set1.add(A), set1.Add(C), set1.Add(C)
```

You can add this finding in an external set, as `finalSet.add(set1)`

```
  Set<Set> finalSet = new HashSet<Set>();
  finalSet.add(set1);
```

This will filter out the duplicates automatically and in the end, you will be left with `A & C` only.

Comment: would throw an exception on the second Add(C)

Comment: [HashSet.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)) --Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false

Comment: You first started by specifying the Set interface, one generally needs to abide by the contract specified in set.  which is this:  The stipulation above does not imply that sets must accept all elements; sets may refuse to add any particular element, including null, and throw an exception, as described in the specification for Collection.add. Individual set implementations should clearly document any restrictions on the elements that they may contain.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: just because a particular Set implementation could reject some element doesn't means that all implementations will. And since the set accepted A at the first call, it will obviously also accept it at the second call. You're just wrong.

Comment: That is correct. I am referring specific implentation class `HashSet`, which should be fine as stated in the description for [HashSet.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)).

Comment: I would remove the reference to java.util.set then (just saying) :)

Comment: The statement normally written is `Set set1 = new HashSet();` so infact, `set1` is `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related with graph theory.

What you can try is to remove that internal list and create a [Incidence Martrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix), that all you objects share.

The final solution mostly depend of the task goal and available structure. So is hard to choose best solution for you problem with the description you have provided.